# In C#, how to change colour of newly added text in Text box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Consider my windows application built using C# VS 2005 displays certain contents in a multi lined text box. Now when i add some new text, it should appear in a different colour. i.e i need to differentiate the text which gets displayed when my project is run and the text that i enter in the text box. how can i do this.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plain [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) control doesn't support multiple colours, fonts etc.

I suspect you'll need to use a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) instead. You can then set the [`SelectionColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor.aspx) property to change the colour of the currently selected text or text inserted at the current insertion point.

I should add that after a few quick experiments, I've found that setting the selection colour and then immediately appending text programmatically doesn't work quite as straightforwardly as I'd hoped. Maybe another answer will explain why :) However, text entered by the user certainly appears in the new colour immediately...

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i will be appending or inserting text in the rich text box manually and not programatically. This text which i insert should get displayed in a different colour.