# how to change colour of newly added text in Rich Text box

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Consider my windows application built using C# VS 2005 displays certain contents in a Rich Text Box. Now when i add some new text, it should appear in a different colour. i.e i need to differentiate the text which gets displayed programmatically and the text that i enter in the text box. how can i do this.?

i.e the font color of the newly inserted text should be different from the text that is already displayed.

PS: Previously i have used text box and changed it to rich text box as told in the below thread.
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846907/in-c-how-to-change-colour-of-newly-added-text-in-text-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {            
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Text inserted by keyboard is red.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, this works:

1. Set the selection start index to the last character.
2. Change selection color.
3. Add new text.
4. Reset selection color.